# In Daniel 12,6-7, is there some significance to the man being "above the waters"?

Tags: genesis, daniel, symbolism, heaven

> [Dan 12:6-7 NASB] (6) And one said to the man dressed in linen, **who was above the waters** of the river, "How long [will it be] until the end of [these] wonders?" (7) I heard the man dressed in linen, **who was above the waters** of the river, as he raised his right hand and his left toward heaven, and swore by Him who lives forever that it would be for a time, times, and half [a] [time;] and as soon as they finish shattering the power of the holy people, all these [events] will be completed.

The phrase "above the waters" seems to be associated with the waters above, as in, above the "firmament" that supports the waters above:

> [Gen 1:6-10 NIV] (6) And God said, "Let there be a vault between the waters to separate water from water." (7) So God made the vault and separated the water under the vault from the water above it. And it was so. (8) God called the vault "sky." And there was evening, and there was morning--the second day. (9) And God said, "Let the water under the sky be gathered to one place, and let dry ground appear." And it was so. (10) God called the dry ground "land," and the gathered waters he called "seas." And God saw that it was good.

> [Psa 148:4 NIV] (4) Praise him, you highest heavens and you waters above the skies.

See also:

> [Rev 10:1-2, 5-9 NLT] (1) Then I saw another mighty angel coming down from heaven, surrounded by a cloud, with a rainbow over his head. His face shone like the sun, and his feet were like pillars of fire. (2) And in his hand was a small scroll that had been opened. **He stood with his right foot on the sea and his left foot on the land. ... (5) Then the angel I saw standing on the sea and on the land raised his right hand toward heaven.** (6) He swore an oath in the name of the one who lives forever and ever, who created the heavens and everything in them, the earth and everything in it, and the sea and everything in it. He said, "There will be no more delay. (7) When the seventh angel blows his trumpet, God's mysterious plan will be fulfilled. It will happen just as he announced it to his servants the prophets." (8) Then the voice from heaven spoke to me again: "Go and take the open scroll from the hand of **the angel who is standing on the sea and on the land.**" (9) So I went to the angel and told him to give me the small scroll. "Yes, take it and eat it," he said. "It will be sweet as honey in your mouth, but it will turn sour in your stomach!"

But what of the man above the waters of the river? Is that significant?

Answer (score 1):

I can see your interest in the passage as it triggers the moment of Jesus walking on water... But here, above the waters of the river means to be further up, on the side of the spring. Spring is used as a source of grace, as we read in Psalms 87:7 (NASB)

> Then those who sing as well as those who play the flutes will say, “All my springs of joy are in you.”

Also, not just a man but "a man dressed in linen". There's three other moments I can think of where such "man" appears. In Daniel 10:5 (NASB)

> I raised my eyes and looked, and behold, there was a man dressed in linen, whose waist had a belt of pure gold of Uphaz.

And in Ezekiel 9:2 (NASB)

> And behold, six men came from the direction of the upper gate which faces north, each with his smashing weapon in his hand; and among them was one man clothed in linen with a scribe’s kit at his waist. And they came in and stood beside the bronze altar.

Then, when it comes to linen, two more others in Revelation 15:6 (NASB)

> and the seven angels who had the seven plagues came out of the temple, clothed in linen, clean and bright, and their chests wrapped with golden sashes.

and in Luke 16:19 (NASB)

> “Now there was a rich man, and he habitually dressed in purple and fine linen, enjoying himself in splendor every day.

From this we extract that being dressed with linen is linked to either purity or opulence.

> But what of the man above the waters of the river? Is that significant?

The signs just seem to point out we're dealing with an angel.